# mysql run out of memory during mview refresh

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-12c, mysql-5.7, materialized-view

I want to create mview from mysql to Oracle using DBLink via odbc driver with Linux 64 bit os. but due to large number of Records around 2.5 cr records it raise the error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Generic Connectivity Using ODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a)
Driver][mysqld-5.7.25-log]MySQL client ran out of memory (SQL State: HY000; SQL
Code: 2008)
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from dblink1
```

I am Using Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production .

mview Syntax :-

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW u1.T_VVS AS SELECT * FROM "m2"."m1"@dblink1
```

I know the question was repeated , but tried all things but result is zero that's why i posted my scenario.

Is there any solution for this ?

let me know if any extra detail required

Comment: Sounds like some kind of space limitation in odbc or mview or oracle.  MySQL will happily stream an arbitrarily large table requested via `SELECT * FROM m2`.  The `MATERIALIZED VIEW` on the other side needs storage somewhere.  (I don't know those details.)

Comment: @RickJames ,  i already checked at oracle side & given full space & everything but i think issue is at the odbc space limitation .